# Is Repair Shop Responsible for Brake Issues?

Tags: brakes, brake-calipers

I recently took my wife's vehicle to a popular repair shop chain to have her brake rotors and pads changed out. I have read many reviews online about this chain being rather shady when it comes to their repairs, but this particular location didn't have any negative reviews, and they were affordable so I figured I'd give them a shot. Less than two months after their work was done, one of the calipers seems to have locked up and destroyed the brand new rotor and pads.

My question is: Is there anything that the shop could have done to cause this lock up? Perhaps a pinched flex hose? If they could be at fault, how should I go about handling this?

Thanks!
Clint

Vehicle Info for reference:
2011 Jeep Grand Cherokee Limited w/ ~100,000 miles. It is the rear driver side caliper.

Comment: Highly unlikely.   Your caliper was probably already corroded and has just got to the point where it started to seize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's *possible* that something they did during the change might be responsible I suppose but usually any such problems would manifest immediately as per the situation in [this question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/18194/seized-brake-caliper-following-brake-pad-disc-replacement-what-could-be-wron).

Unfortunately given this has happened ~ 2 months later you'll have a hard time *proving* that anything they did was responsible so I don't think you are going to get anywhere attempting to pursue the garage for this.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Right now the vehicle is sitting at the same shop, and later this morning I have an appointment to get it inspected. I wasn't sure if this was worth mentioning to them or not...

Comment: You could always mention that you had the pads/rotors changed - they may give some good will gesture but I'd just be prepared for them not to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

I have regular locking up issues with my '06 F250. I'm in the NE with plenty of road salt exposure and the truck sits (outside) sometimes for several days without use.

Fairly often one of the corners locks up due to rust forming on some of the caliper parts.  It usually frees itself but not always.  I can smell the brakes when I get out of the truck after a drive. And the wheel itself will be, ahem, hot!

I am unaware if Jeeps have the same trouble.

Comment: BTW, the dealer fixed this under warranty back when the truck was new but doesn't now.  They recommend a $200-$300 "brake service" whereby they apparently clean and lube some of the bits.

Comment: I haven't had any issues in the ~15 months we've owned the vehicle, but I think the caliper is locked up for good. The once shiny new rotor now looks destroyed, and it doesn't seem to be releasing. I'm probably going to have the caliper replaced, I just was curious if the shop had any sort of responsibility towards this. Perhaps nicking the rubber boot on the caliper or something of that sort.

Comment: Absolutely mention it to the shop.  Even small shops that *should* remember you seem to conveniently NOT.  "Come backs" are expensive to them.